# creating a java program to extract svn logs and store them in xml

Tags: java, svn, logging

I'd like to make a GUI that will take in a file directory and start date, and then find the svn logs associated with that directory and time frame.  Once I have the information, I can then parse it and store it in an xml.  The trouble is just getting the logs and reading the information off of them.

I've got svn client and can use the command line to retrieve information, but I want my java program to do this for me.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Please let me know if you have any questions that I can help you with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is SVNKit which is a Java SVN Library

http://svnkit.com/

Also, note that SVN log already has the `--xml` flag which will generate it in xml form.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re15.html